# How do I multiply corresponding elements in numpy arrays efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multiplication

Given a numpy array `x` of shape `(m,)` and a numpy array `y` of shape `(m/n,)`, how do I multiply `x` by corresponding elements of `y` efficiently?

Here's my best attempt:

```
In [13]: x = np.array([1, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1])

In [14]: y = np.array([2, 4, 6])

In [15]: n = 2

In [16]: (y[:, np.newaxis] * x.reshape((-1, n))).flatten()
Out[16]: array([ 2, 10, 12,  8, 54,  6])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks pretty good to me.

If you wanted to speed it up slightly, you could:

- Use `ravel()` instead of `flatten()` (the former will return a view if possible, the latter always returns a copy).
- Reshape `x` in Fortran order to avoid the overhead of another indexing operation on `y` (*although subsequent timings suggest this speedup is negligible*)

So rewritten the multiplication becomes:

```
>>> (x.reshape((2, -1), order='f') * y).ravel('f')
array([ 2, 10, 12,  8, 54,  6])
```

Timings:

```
>>> %timeit (y[:, np.newaxis] * x.reshape((-1, n))).flatten()
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.4 µs per loop

>>> %timeit (x.reshape((n, -1), order='f') * y).ravel('f')
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.98 µs per loop
```

Comment: I imagine the speed increase will be more pronounced for longer vectors.

Comment: @NeilG - you're right, a quick test for `x` of length 1000000 and `y` of length `500000` suggests it's faster by a factor of 10 (much more that I'd imagined). Most of the speedup comes from using `ravel()`.